# Year instead of Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I do this to get the earliest year:

```
select top 1 tblOrders.OrderDate from tblOrders order by tblOrders.OrderDate
```

What would I need to do to get the year instead of the date presuming OrderDate is of type date.

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [YEAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function:

```
SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(tblOrders.OrderDate)
    FROM tblOrders 
    ORDER BY tblOrders.OrderDate
```